# Matplotlib no object 'Use' or '__version__'

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

Matplotlib seems to be broken on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I'm not sure what could've changed from a few days ago. Can somebody offer any suggestions to fix the fact that I cannot import attributes from matplotlib? Thanks -

I installed (and re-installed) using:

```
git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
python setup.py install
```

Errors:

```
>>> from matplotlib import *
>>> import matplotlib 
>>> matplotlib.use('Agg')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'use'

>>> matplotlib.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Answer (score 2):

This error could happen if you named a script `matplotlib.py` and have it in a directory listed your PYTHONPATH. Your matplotlib.py script may be masking the "real" package.

One way to test if this is the case is to look at `matplotlib.__file__`.

```
>>> matplotlib.use('Agg')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'use'
>>> matplotlib.__file__
'/home/unutbu/pybin/matplotlib.py'
>>>
```

The fix is to rename your `matplotlib.py` something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when I do a 'locate matplotlib.py' command, I don't find any files named matplotlib.py. Also, when I do the __matplotlib.__file I get the following. Any other suggestions?                                                      >>> import matplotlib
>>> 
>>> matplotlib.__file__
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'